# Background image above border

Tags: html, css

I don't get it. I want a simple line with arrow so I use a class with border and a background-image:

```
hr {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-top:dotted #000 1px;
    background: #fff url("img/arrow.gif") no-repeat 100px -1px;
 }
```

Unfortunately the background is below the border:

[image]

I've tried `z-index`, "id beats class" (with `<hr id="arrow">`) but nothing worked. Is there a solution?

BTW, how the css-cracks would do such a dotted line with arrow?

Comment: Is your arrow.gif transparent?

Comment: I guess position -1 is not enough, try, -2 or -3

Comment: Just sussed out a way of doing this without :after - jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/T8Yzj/39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​**EDIT:** I've been looking at doing this without :after, only because I don't like being downvoted :)

The best I can come up with is this:

```
.box3 {
    z-index: 100;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 0 30px 0;    
    background-image: url("http://test.mark-design.co.uk/4ik4e7ic.png"), url('http://test.mark-design.co.uk/line.png');
    background-position: 50% -1px, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

It uses the multiple backgrounds in CSS3 so it won't be massively supported yet but works and is a fairly interesting way of doing it - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/T8Yzj/39/

The image needs tweaking as does the padding but the result is sound.

Comment: It's going to be. Just wanted to get something down quickly while I work on it...

Comment: He's having the image, doesn't want to accomplish using CSS

Comment: Then he can't do it. He needs CSS.

Comment: Its bad practice to just jot down a bad answer while you work on something bigger and better... its not a race.

Comment: he can certainly do it, he's having that triangle gif, but you shouldn't get that -1, your solution is not wrong, it's just not applicable to what he is asking

Comment: @Mr. Alien The answer is correct and applicable – but meaningless. It's like answering the question "How do one see the moon?" with "Open your eyes."

Comment: @feeela Exactly, I mean answer is perfect but on a different question

Comment: @feeela - as I hate being down voted I have done a new example using multiple backgrounds. No pseudo elements. Not massively supported but quite interesting...

Answer (score 3):

A background image is always wrapped by the containers border.

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel

You will need an additional element below to add the arrow. This could be achieved by using `:after` on the desired element.

```
/* not tested */
hr {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}

hr:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px; top:0px;
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
    background: transparent url("img/arrow.gif") no-repeat right top;
}
```

Comment: Just sussed out a way of doing this without :after - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/T8Yzj/39/

Comment: Fine, thank you, works perfekt in FF.
In IE (9.x) and Opera, I just see the dotted line. In Chrome I see the arrow but the dotted border goes through... Is there a solution for all browsers or is it better to do such a dooted line with arrow as a whole image?

Comment: background-clip can override that rule and you can run background images under the border: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Comment: @worc As this answer was orignally posted the `background-clip` property was not ready for cross browser usage. You may also could have updated the answer instead of downvoting it…

Comment: @feeela i could've, but it would drastically change the content of the answer. i have points to spare, so i did the next best thing and pushed the answer down and provided some new information that i had come across.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CSS triangles instead of an image:

```
<hr class="arrow">
```

css:

```
.arrow {
    position:relative
}

.arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 10px solid #000;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh2x3/)